# The webcam stays black when i am trying to build a Vuforia App for a Microsoft Surface Book

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, webcam, vuforia

my problem is that i am trying to build a Vuforia based application in Unity with the Image Target feature for the Microsoft Surface Book (which is supported by Vuforia). The application is working good in the Unity Editor Play Mode. Everything fits fine and the webcam of my notebook is getting initialized when i am starting Play Mode. Now in case I wanna build a stand alone application out of the project the build application is starting fine, but is not initializing any webcam. The AR view just stays black. Do anyone know a tip to solve this? (in case i am building the same project on android everything works btw, but i need it on the surface working)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the weird thing is, that the code is able to find the webcam(s), but not able to start them? i wrote some code to find out if the app struggles to find webcams in general, but thats not the case. its a problem, that the webcams are never getting activated

Answer (score 2):

Vuforia Engine has some limitations on which cameras it can use, for example it won't work with a 'front' (user facing) camera. If you have multiple cameras connected to your device try going into Device Manager and disabling any cameras that you don't want to use before launching your App.

Do you face the same problem if you build the Vuforia Core sample from the Asset Store? - https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/templates/packs/vuforia-core-samples-99026

Are you able to capture the Vuforia Engine logs on your Surface Book as they may help diagnose this issue? see https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/capturing-and-viewing-event-logs-etw - the article mentions Hololens but it also applies to other Windows devices.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with the Surface Book, but on many devices each application needs to be granted access to your webcam. Sometimes when people have published their first application, I've seen them accidently click 'no' to granting permission to their application for access, or sometimes I've seen devices that automatically block access to equipment (like webcams) from applications build by unknown developers. You might try looking into the permissions for your webcam and/or the application in question.

Comment: that was my first look. the system accidently denied the permission by its own, but after giving the application the permission it stays black D:

Comment: https://ibb.co/zH6sXWX
https://ibb.co/yRyYfLb
here are my screenshots. the first one is the proof, that the permission is granted and the seccond one is inside the app my pov when i need the camera but nothing happens.
just in case thats important i am building the application at the moment on my laptop which have an intern webcam instead on the surface